# How to add OR merge JSON data into a JSON field of an existing MySQL row?

Tags: mysql, json

I have an existing table like that:

```
id | json
---+----------
1  | {"1":"1"}
2  | NULL
```

and i want to be able to merge `{"2":"2"}` into any one of the existing rows wheater or not the json field already contains JSON or is NULL. 
That it looks like that:

```
id | json
---+----------
1  | {"1":"1", "2":"2"}
2  | {"2":"2"}
```

with `UPDATE table SET json = CAST('{"2":"2"}' AS JSON) WHERE id=1)` I can only update the second row or overwrite the first one.

with `UPDATE table SET json = JSON_MERGE(json, CAST('{"2":"2"}' AS JSON) WHERE id=1)` I can only update the first row, the second row stays unchanged.

Is there a single command that accounts for both cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to `COALESCE` the current `json` column to the equivalent of empty string in JSON terms:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET json = JSON_MERGE(COALESCE(json, CAST('{}' AS JSON)), CAST('{"2":"2"}' AS JSON))
WHERE id = 1;
```

Another quick and dirty approach here would be to use a `CASE` expression to decide whether you merge or simply overwrite:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET json = CASE WHEN json IS NOT NULL
                THEN JSON_MERGE(json, CAST('{"2":"2"}' AS JSON))
                ELSE CAST('{"2":"2"}' AS JSON) END
WHERE id = 1;
```